# PHP unable to open folder for writing. permission denied. Using wampserver2

Tags: php, wamp, file-permissions, wampserver

Anybody know how to get around this with wampserver2?

I'm trying to use this thumbnail generator http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/

Answer (score -1):

You will have to give the user under which the server is running write access to the folder.

Comment: That's what i don't know how to do

Comment: which os do you have (version)?

Comment: windows. WampServer is windows apache mysql php

Comment: just right click on the folder go to properties then security tab and check there.

Comment: If you right click on the tab you can uncheck the read only box and click ok, but when you right click on the folder, the read only box is checked

Comment: After trying a few things, I don't even think i'm asking a question that pertains to my issue anymore. Voting to close.